# Basic Series RLC circuit with LTspice

Tags: ltspice

The L and C have the same impedance at 14.529kHz. The series LC is at resonant frequency and should act as a short. Therefore R2 should have the same current as R1. However it is nowhere close. When I build this same circuit in Eagle I get the correct results. Why am I not getting the correct results in LTspice?

Note: V1, C2 and L5 are ideal (no internal resistance).
EDIT! L5 was NOT IDEAL (Rpar=65k), when ideal AND timestep=1n, this circuit works as expected.

[image]

The LTspice file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/anci5907ybx8c4v/Tank_serial_v01_v05.asc?dl=0

Comment: Try using 1ns instead of 1us for the max step size, to start. Also, just in case, make sure you use more digits of precision for the frequency, as well. Together, those things should get you near where you want to be. But I wonder about the step size more. In fact, change your .TRAN card to ".TRAN 0 40m 39m 1n" and see how that works.

Comment: Can you also post a screenshot of your setup in Eagle? Just tried it in LTspice and I see the currents displaced by 90 degrees, unlike your picture. As soon as I impose a tighter timestep, as @jonk suggested, everything goes fine.

Comment: @jonk - Thank you for those suggestions but I get the exact same results. I added a link to my LTspice file with the changes you suggested. Maybe my LTspice program is having issues? I did a Sync Release prior to posting my questions.

Comment: @a-concerned-citizen - I don't like using Eagle and find it frusterating. I was just barely able to simulate this circuit in Eagle and I could only verify the results by checking the peak current of the current trace on R2 with the plot cursor. It gave me 11.5A (should be 12A). LTspice is giving 2A. See my comment to jonk.

Comment: @Rick Why did you say you have ideal L when you have Rpar=65469? As soon as you set that to zero, even a 1u timestep will give a close call. You don't even need to simulate with a 1ns timestep, 100n will do just fine.

Comment: @a-concerned-citizen, you are right, thanks. I forgot that was still in there however it is Rpar and not Rser which is 0. When I make Rpar = 0 the R2 peak current goes to 11.11A when it should be 12A. Much better but not correct. Whey I try an arbitrary different set of values like C2=900p, L5=900u, Freq=176.839k you get very incorrect results again of R2=3.27Apeak (instead of 12A). EDIT: Like jonk said, it is most likely the timestep! When I reduce to 1n it gives correct results! I had no idea LTspice was so sensitive to the timestep needing to be so low for some solutions.

Comment: This is a very simple circuit, with barely any dynamics, if any, and completely linear, so the solver will fly over it with very large timesteps for the solver. If you need precision (which is what you're after), then you need to impose a timestep. How small depends on your goals and applications.

Comment: @Rick As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTepA.png), I'm not having any problems with LTspice. Just "looks right." The time step does matter -- mostly, that's the "go to" check-and-see-to-be-sure issue when you are having problems that make no sense to you. If it still shows nonsensical results after you've tightened up a lot on the time step, then you move to other issues.

Comment: @a-concerned-citizen, thank you very much for your time/help. The solution to my question is to greatly reduced the timestep (in my case timestep=1n and my L5 Rpar value was effecting the solutions as well).

Comment: @jonk - thank you! A new sort-of-related question. I had Rpar=65K. I thought that is the resistance between the windings. Therefore I ignored/forgot about it. However with the very high voltages created by the series LC resonant circuit (about 3kV) that started to play a major factor? Even though the voltage differential between each turn would be very small.

Comment: @Rick I read "V1, C2 and L5 are ideal" and stopped at that point. I don't know when you added the .ASC text of your schematic, but I never did see it. So, I missed that fact, entirely. And yes, of course it would matter a lot. My mistake in missing that aspect.

Comment: @jonk It was only added about 1h ago. I was writing a comment when I saw the OP being updated, otherwise I wouldn't have seen it, either, since OP never mentioned anything about it.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen That explains a lot. We went down a rabbit hole. Oh, well.

Comment: @jonk, ya sorry. I have now edited my questions stating that incorrect info.

Comment: @Rick Just FYI: Without the 65k parallel resistance the impedance is just \$4\:\Omega\$, as you'd expected. But with it, you get \$22.49\:\Omega\:\angle -0.79355^\circ\$, which is a lot different.

Comment: @jonk I have been scratching my head on what does the Rpar value really mean. I thought it was the resistance between the windings but it is not. I'm still researching but it looks like it is the magnetic core losses. 
This article explains how to measure and calculate Cpar and Rpar for real inductors. Search the article on "parallel".
http://www.intusoft.com/articles/inductor.pdf

Comment: @Rick Actually it's just that, a shunt resistor. If you look in the help at `LTspice > Circuit Elements > L. Inductor` you'll see exactly what it means, and the others (also check `... > ... > C. Capacitor`, maybe also read the text a bit, it may be worth it). Core losses can be modeled with a shunt resistor, but it's not the other way around, though. I would say that a program's own help should be the first to go to for problems and clarifications, and only go to the Internet if you still have questions.